# Derivative Matrix with general function and product

Tags: matrix-calculus

Given $F,f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ such that $F'=f$ and $\pmb a,\pmb b\in\mathbb R^n$, compute
$$\frac{d}{d\pmb X}\left(\pmb a^T F\left(\pmb X\right)\pmb b\right)$$
where $\pmb X\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$.

---

My guess is $\operatorname{diag}(\pmb b) f(\pmb X)^T\operatorname{diag}(\pmb a)$ but I would like to
(i) confirm it and
(ii) see if there's a better way than using indices.

Comment: $\def\D{\operatorname{Diag}}$You're close, just drop the transpose $\;\D(a)f(X)\D(b)\quad$ This assumes that the functions are applied elementwise.

Comment: Sorry I had $\operatorname{diag}(\pmb a)$ and $\operatorname{diag}(\pmb b)$ swapped. What do you think now? I'm following the definition found here: https://tminka.github.io/papers/matrix/minka-matrix.pdf

Comment: The swapped version is consistent, however the transposition of the entire formula is something called the _layout convention_ which varies from textbook to  textbook. I happen to prefer the opposite convention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, note that $a^TF(X)b=\operatorname{tr}(a^TF(X)b)=\operatorname{tr}(ba^TF(X))$. So using differentials we have

$$d\operatorname{tr}(ba^TF(X))=\operatorname{tr}(ba^TdF(X))=\operatorname{tr}(ba^Tf(X)\odot dX)=ab^T\cdot f(X)\odot dX=$$
$$=ab^T\odot f(X)\cdot dX$$
As $\operatorname{tr}(A^TB)=A\cdot B$,  where $A\cdot B=\sum_{i,j}A_{i,j}B_{i,j}$ for matrices of the same dimensions. $\odot$ - Hadamard product.

From this we see that
$$\frac{d}{dX}\left(a^T F\left(X\right)b\right)=ab^T\odot f(X)$$
Also note $ab^T\odot f(X)=\operatorname{diag}(a)f(X)\operatorname{diag}(b)$.

I have used notations and properties of operations from [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.304.5533).